# Dell xps 15 (l521x) Dualboot with windows 8.1 and ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-8.1

My dell xps 15 has 1TB HDD and 32G SSD. I've installed newest ubuntu on SSD (before that I've disabled Intel Smart Response Technology by setting ATA operation to AHCI in BIOS) and after that I've installed windows 8.1 on HDD. Strange thing is that I cannot disable Intel Rapid Start Technology because it is grayed out in BIOS.

The problem is that after a day of using both operating systems my Windows 8.1 fails to boot going to infinite loop of repairing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start Ubuntu? If you can, go directly to step 2.

1) download an Ubuntu image, and burn it to a USB stick/CD. Booth from it, select *Try Ubuntu without installing it*, then:

2) download [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), and follow the instructions in this Ubuntu Wiki Page. They are sufficient to solve most boot problems (not all, just most of them).

If this does not work, still Boot Repair will provide an extremely useful error report, which may constitute the basis for the next step.